# List of printing format in Go lang

Tags: formatting, go

Just want to know the list of printing format using the fmt package's functions.

For example, like:

%v is use for print the value.
%T can print the type of value.

What else?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The list of format "verbs" is available in the [**documentation of the fmt package**](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) :

**General:**

```
%v  the value in a default format.
    when printing structs, the plus flag (%+v) adds field names
%#v a Go-syntax representation of the value
%T  a Go-syntax representation of the type of the value
%%  a literal percent sign; consumes no value
```

**Boolean:**

```
%t  the word true or false
```

**Integer:**

```
%b  base 2
%c  the character represented by the corresponding Unicode code point
%d  base 10
%o  base 8
%q  a single-quoted character literal safely escaped with Go syntax.
%x  base 16, with lower-case letters for a-f
%X  base 16, with upper-case letters for A-F
%U  Unicode format: U+1234; same as "U+%04X"
```

**Floating-point and complex constituents:**

```
%b  decimalless scientific notation with exponent a power of two,
    in the manner of strconv.FormatFloat with the 'b' format,
    e.g. -123456p-78
%e  scientific notation, e.g. -1234.456e+78
%E  scientific notation, e.g. -1234.456E+78
%f  decimal point but no exponent, e.g. 123.456
%g  whichever of %e or %f produces more compact output
%G  whichever of %E or %f produces more compact output
```

**String and slice of bytes:**

```
%s  the uninterpreted bytes of the string or slice
%q  a double-quoted string safely escaped with Go syntax
%x  base 16, lower-case, two characters per byte
%X  base 16, upper-case, two characters per byte
```

**Pointer:**

```
%p  base 16 notation, with leading 0x
```

**Other flags:**

```
+   always print a sign for numeric values;
    guarantee ASCII-only output for %q (%+q)
-   pad with spaces on the right rather than the left (left-justify the field)
#   alternate format: add leading 0 for octal (%#o), 0x for hex (%#x);
    0X for hex (%#X); suppress 0x for %p (%#p);
    print a raw (backquoted) string if possible for %q (%#q);
    write e.g. U+0078 'x' if the character is printable for %U (%#U).
' ' (space) leave a space for elided sign in numbers (% d);
    put spaces between bytes printing strings or slices in hex (% x, % X)
0   pad with leading zeros rather than spaces
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, there is helpful for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can find out more, check this out http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/

and run

```
$ godoc -http=0.0.0.0:8080
```

browser open localhost:8080 to get entire offline go website (also including your go src & doc)

Comment: You can just do `:8080` (although usually port 6060 is used).