# How to pad a number with zeros when printing?

Tags: go, format

How can I print a number or make a string with zero padding to make it fixed width?

For instance, if I have the number `12` and I want to make it `000012`.

Answer (score 334):

The fmt package can do this for you:

```
fmt.Printf("|%06d|%6d|\n", 12, 345)
```

Output:

```
|000012|   345|
```

Notice the 0 in %06d, that will make it a width of 6 and pad it with zeros. The second one will pad with spaces.

Try it for yourself here: http://play.golang.org/p/cinDspMccp

Comment: What if I want the pad to be to the right? using the flag `-` only gives spaces, I need zeros.

Comment: If you want a string to later work with, use `Sprintf` instead of `Printf`

Comment: @majidarif padding with zeroes on the right turns 345 into 345000, which is kind of a different number.

Comment: @hobbs right padding a hex string has its uses. Consider 4 bytes right-padded 0s (e.g. ip address of "C0" is "192.0.0.0") or 3 byte colors padded with the right most symbol (e.g. "FFF" is "FFFFFF" or 255 255 255 for white)

Comment: @JoshHibschman if you want to compute a different, related value, you can do so, but it goes well beyond the kind of formatting that printf does.

Answer (score 135):

Use the `Printf` function from the [fmt package](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) with a `width` of `6` and the padding character `0`:

```
import "fmt"
fmt.Printf("%06d", 12) // Prints to stdout '000012'
```

Setting the **width** works by putting an integer directly preceding the format specifier ('verb'):

```
fmt.Printf("%d", 12)   // Uses default width,                          prints '12'
fmt.Printf("%6d", 12)  // Uses a width of 6 and left pads with spaces, prints '    12'
```

The only **padding characters** supported by Golang (and most other languages) are spaces and `0`:

```
fmt.Printf("%6d", 12)   // Default padding is spaces, prints '    12'
fmt.Printf("%06d", 12)  // Change to 0 padding,       prints '000012'
```

It is possible to **right-justify** the printing by prepending a minus `-`:

```
fmt.Printf("%-6d", 12)   // Padding right-justified, prints '12    '
```

Beware that for **floating point numbers** the width includes the whole format string:

```
fmt.Printf("%06.1f", 12.0) // Prints '0012.0' (width is 6, precision is 1 digit)
```

It is useful to note that the width can also be set programmatically by using `*` instead of a number and passing the width as an `int` parameter:

```
myWidth := 6
fmt.Printf("%0*d", myWidth, 12) // Prints '000012' as before
```

This might be useful for instance if the largest value you want to print is only known at runtime (called `maxVal` in the following example):

```
myWidth := 1 + int(math.Log10(float64(maxVal)))
fmt.Printf("%*d", myWidth, nextVal)
```

Last, if you don't want to print to `stdout` but return a String, use `Sprintf` also from [fmt package](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) with the same parameters:

```
s := fmt.Sprintf("%06d", 12) // returns '000012' as a String
```

Comment: That programmatic padding length is a gem, thank you!

Answer (score 40):

There is one simplest way to achieve this. Use

```
func padNumberWithZero(value uint32) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%02d", value)
}
```

`fmt.Sprintf` formats and returns a string without printing it anywhere.
Here `%02d` says pad zero on left for value who has < 2 number of digits. If given value has 2 or more digits it will not pad. For example:

- If input is 1, output will be 01.
- If input is 12, output will be 12.
- If input is 1992, output will be 1992.

You can use `%03d` or more for more zeros padding.

Answer (score 13):

Just in case if you want to prefix or suffix to form another word by concatenating you can use below code.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    concatenatedWord:= "COUNTER_"+fmt.Sprintf("%02d", 1)
    // use concatenatedWord 
        fmt.Println("ConcatenatedWordword is", concatenatedWord)
}
```

output : **ConcatenatedWordword is COUNTER_01**

link : https://play.golang.org/p/25g3L8TXiPP

Answer (score 12):

The question "[List of printing format in Go lang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12781811/6309)" reminds us that there is also the flag:

> `-`   pad with spaces on the right rather than the left (left-justify the field)

---

You can see more padding examples with [`DaddyOh/golang-samples/pad.go`](https://github.com/git-time-metric/gtm/blob/master/util/string.go#L53-L88), if you want to pad with other string sequences (more complex than '`0`' or ''):

- `leftPad(s string, padStr string, pLen int)`
- `rightPad(s string, padStr string, pLen int)`
- `leftPad2Len(s string, padStr string, overallLen int)`
- `rightPad2Len(s string, padStr string, overallLen int)`

See [<kbd>play.golang.org</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/8Icse1Hjsb):

```
1234567890

leftPad(str, "*", 3)  ***1234567890
leftPad2Len(str, "*-", 13)  -*-1234567890
leftPad2Len(str, "*-", 14)  *-*-1234567890
leftPad2Len(str, "*", 14)  ****1234567890
leftPad2Len(str, "*-x", 14)  x*-x1234567890
leftPad2Len(str, "ABCDE", 14)  BCDE1234567890
leftPad2Len(str, "ABCDE", 4)  7890
rightPad(str, "*", 3)  1234567890***
rightPad(str, "*!", 3)  1234567890*!*!*!
rightPad2Len(str, "*-", 13)  1234567890*-*
rightPad2Len(str, "*-", 14)  1234567890*-*-
rightPad2Len(str, "*", 14)  1234567890****
rightPad2Len(str, "*-x", 14)  1234567890*-x*
rightPad2Len(str, "ABCDE", 14)  1234567890ABCD
rightPad2Len(str, "ABCDE", 4)  1234
```

Comment: Eric Palmer removed his repo with golang samples so link isn't working anymore.

Comment: @KonstantinAzizov Good point. I have restored that link. Sort of.

Answer (score 7):

```
func lpad(s string,pad string, plength int)string{
    for i:=len(s);i<plength;i++{
        s=pad+s
    }
    return s
}
```

lpad("3","0",2)  result: "03"

lpad("12","0",6)  result: "000012"

Answer (score 4):

```
fmt.Printf("%012s", "345")
```

Result: `000000000345`

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution:

```golang
func leftZeroPad(number, padWidth int64) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf(fmt.Sprintf("%%0%dd", padWidth), number)
}
```

Example usage:

```golang
fmt.Printf("%v", leftZeroPad(12, 10))
```

prints:

```
0000000012
```

The advantage of this is that you can specify the pad length at run time if needed.

Answer (score 1):

For those that want to right pad, you can do this:

```
str2pad := "12"
padWith := "0"
amt2pad := 6

//This will make sure there is always 6 characters total, padded on the right side
//Note to check if strings.Repeat returns a negative value
paddedStr := str2pad + strings.Repeat(padWith, amt2pad - len(str2pad))

//Outputs 120000
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the `golang.org/x/text/number` package:

```
package main

import (
   "golang.org/x/text/language"
   "golang.org/x/text/message"
   "golang.org/x/text/number"
)

var fmt = message.NewPrinter(language.English)

func main() {
   n := number.Decimal(
      12, number.Pad('0'), number.FormatWidth(6),
   )
   fmt.Println(n) // 000012
}
```

https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/text/number