# How to convert int64 to binary and keep leading zeros in golang?

Tags: go

I have created a program which converts int64 to binary:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    n := int64(3)
    fmt.Println(strconv.FormatInt(n, 2))
}
```

And it returns this value:

```
11
```

How can I keep the leading zeros in the answer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Golang: How to pad a number with zeros when printing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25637440/golang-how-to-pad-a-number-with-zeros-when-printing)

Comment: See https://play.golang.org/p/lS0DoMLth6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can format directly as binary with padding:

```
fmt.Printf("%064b\n", n)
```

See https://play.golang.org/p/JHCgyPMKDG

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
func main() {
    n := int64(3)
    s := strconv.FormatInt(n, 2)
    fmt.Printf("%064s", s)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/23IGYPYaE8