# Usage example for Format method with leading zero padding for Big Ints in Golang

Tags: string, go, string-formatting

I would like to format a big int as a string with leading zeros.  I'm looking for an example similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25637440/how-to-pad-a-number-with-zeros-when-printing), but with Big:

I'm looking at source [here](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Format).

But when I call:

```
m := big.NewInt(99999999999999)
fmt.Println(m.Format("%010000000000000000000","d"))
```

I see:

```
prog.go:10:22: m.Format("%010000000000000000000", "d") used as value
prog.go:10:23: cannot use "%010000000000000000000" (type string) as type fmt.State in argument to m.Format:
    string does not implement fmt.State (missing Flag method)
prog.go:10:48: cannot use "d" (type string) as type rune in argument to m.Format
```

(I understand normally I can use m.String(), but zero padding seems to complicate this, so I'm looking specifically for some help on the Format method.)

Here's [my playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/7Uz2trkM8Fo).

Comment: Thanks, everyone.  I just forgot Sprintf.  :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use [`fmt.Sprintf(...)`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf) with the `"%020s"` directive (where 20 is whatever total length you want). The `s` verb will use the natural string format of the big int and the `020` modifier will create a string with total length of (at least) 20 with zero padding (instead of whitespace).

For example ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.com/p/nnCWsePPvTT)):

```
m := big.NewInt(99999999999999)
s := fmt.Sprintf("%020s", m)
fmt.Println(s)
// 00000099999999999999
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`Int.Format()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Format) is not for you to call manually (although you could), but it is to implement [`fmt.Formatter`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Formatter) so the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package will support formatting [`big.Int`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int) values out-of-the box.

See this example:

```
m := big.NewInt(99)
fmt.Printf("%06d\n", m)

if _, ok := m.SetString("1234567890123456789012345678901234567890", 10); !ok {
    panic("big")
}
fmt.Printf("%060d\n", m)
```

Outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/6bg7Y1uZ6-X)):

```
000099
000000000000000000001234567890123456789012345678901234567890
```

This is the simplest, so use this. Manually creating an `fmt.Formatter` gives you more control, but is also harder to do it. Unless this is a performance critical part of your app, just use the above solution.

Comment: I would like to store the string, not print it.

Comment: @Mittenchops You didn't mention that in your question, and the example you provided also prints to the console. Everything I wrote in the answer still applies, you just have to use `fmt.Sprintf()` instead of `fmt.Printf()`. For more details, see [Format a Go string without printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123865/format-a-go-string-without-printing/31742265#31742265)