# Write fixed length padded lines to file Go

Tags: go, byte, padding

For printing, justified and fixed length, seems like what everyone asks about and there are many examples that I have found, like...

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    values := []string{"Mustang", "10", "car"}
    for i := range(values) {
        fmt.Printf("%10v...\n", values[i])
    }

    for i := range(values) {
        fmt.Printf("|%-10v|\n", values[i])
    }
}
```

**Situation**

But what if I need to WRITE to a file with fixed length bytes?

For example: what if I have requirement that states, write this line to a file that must be 32 bytes, left justified and padded to the right with 0's

**Question**

So, how do you accomplish this when writing to a file?

Comment: Then you use `fmt.Fprintf()` instead of `fmt.Printf()`.

Comment: Or `fmt.Sprintf()` if you want to have strings.

Comment: Also relevant : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25637440/how-to-pad-a-number-with-zeros-when-printing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are analogous functions to `fmt.PrintXX()` functions, ones that start with an `F`, take the form of `fmt.FprintXX()`. These variants write the result to an [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) which may be an [`os.File`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File) as well.

So if you have the [`fmt.Printf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf) statements which you want to direct to a file, just change them to call [`fmt.Fprintf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fprint) instead, passing the file as the first argument:

```
var f *os.File = ... // Initialize / open file

fmt.Fprintf(f, "%10v...\n", values[i])
```

If you look into the implementation of `fmt.Printf()`:

```
func Printf(format string, a ...interface{}) (n int, err error) {
    return Fprintf(os.Stdout, format, a...)
}
```

It does exactly this: it calls `fmt.Fprintf()`, passing `os.Stdout` as the output to write to.

For how to open a file, see [How to read/write from/to file using Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821811/how-to-read-write-from-to-file-using-go)

See related question: [Format a Go string without printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123865/format-a-go-string-without-printing/31742265#31742265)

Comment: Thanks all, think that has helped my understanding and pointed me in the right direction.  Knowing what questions to ask helps.  Also, for anyone else reading this, I found these handy functions for padding.  RightPad2Len https://github.com/DaddyOh/golang-samples/blob/master/pad.go