# Idiomatic way to Concat Leading Zeros in Go

Tags: go, idioms, leading-zero

I came up with a way to pad leading zeros into a Go string.  I'm not sure if this is the way you do this in Go.  Is there a proper way to do this in Go?  This is what I came up with and can be found inside the second if block.  I tried Google to see if it had something built in without luck.

```
func integerToStringOfFixedWidth(n int, w int) string {
  s := strconv.Itoa(n)
  l := len(s)

  if l < w {
    for i := l; i < w; i++ {
      s = "0" + s
    }
    return s
  }
  if l > w {
    return s[l-w:]
  }
  return s
}
```

For n = 1234 and w = 5, the output should be
integerToStringOfFixedWidth(n, w) = "01234".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Golang: How to pad a number with zeros when printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25637440/golang-how-to-pad-a-number-with-zeros-when-printing)

Answer (score 6):

You can use Sprintf/Printf for that (Use Sprintf with the same format to print to a string):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    // For fixed width
    fmt.Printf("%05d", 4)

    // Or if you need variable widths:
    fmt.Printf("%0*d", 5, 1234)
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/

> See other flags in the docs - pad with leading zeros rather than spaces

https://play.golang.org/p/0EM4aE2Hk6H

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
func integerToStringOfFixedWidth(n, w int) string {
    s := fmt.Sprintf(fmt.Sprintf("%%0%dd", w), n)
    l := len(s)
    if l > w {
        return s[l-w:]
    }
    return s
}
```

Comment: I was going to ask the poster above how you can return that and now I see how that is done.

Comment: Consider also `fmt.Sprintf("%0*d", w, n)`, which is a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Use a well documented and tested package instead of writing your own paddig code.  Here's how to use [github.com/keltia/leftpad](https://godoc.org/github.com/keltia/leftpad):

```
func integerToStringOfFixedWidth(n int, w int) string {
    s, _ := leftpad.PadChar(strconv.Itoa(n), w, '0')
    return s
}
```

[Run this code on the Golang Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bYmX7n08uZf)!