# Print data in form of table

Tags: go

I have a code, that prints values to 3 columns, but i can't print them in straight columns

```
fmt.Printf("%d       | %.1f      | %.5f      | \n", int(i), x, val)
```

I'm getting this:

```
0       | 0.0      | error      | 
1       | 90.0      | error      |
2       | 180.0      | -0.00000      |
3       | 270.0      | 3.94795      |
4       | 360.0      | error      |
5       | 450.0      | error      |
6       | 540.0      | -0.00000      |
7       | 630.0      | 3.94795      |
8       | 720.0      | error      |
```

I couldn't find a way to do this in go.

Comment: use one of the many ascii table output modules

Comment: You should specify [width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25637440/golang-how-to-pad-a-number-with-zeros-when-printing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look at [tabwriter](https://pkg.go.dev/text/tabwriter)

> Package tabwriter implements a write filter (tabwriter.Writer) that translates tabbed columns in input into properly aligned text.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "text/tabwriter"
)

func main() {
    w := tabwriter.NewWriter(os.Stdout, 10, 1, 1, ' ', tabwriter.Debug)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%d\t%v\t%v\t\n", 0, 0.0, "error")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%d\t%v\t%v\t\n", 0, 90.0, "error")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%d\t%v\t%v\t\n", 7, 630.0, 3.94795)
    w.Flush()
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/_u5W46AZ5sq